# Exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Invalid block type' Magento 1

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, blocks, exception, page

The following exceptions are showing in my exception log. Could anyone help to resolve that issue and clean my exception log?

```
exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Invalid block type: Mage_Page_Block_Html_Under'

exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Invalid block type: Mage_Page_Block_Html_Nocart'

exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Invalid block type: Mage_Page_Block_Html_Prefooter'
```

In theme layout folder `page.xml` something is written like the follow way:

```
<block type="page/html_nocart" name="no_cart_message" as="no_cart_message" template="page/html/nocart.phtml">
    <block type="cms/block" name="no_cart" as="no_cart">
        <action method="setBlockId">
            <block_id>no_cart</block_id></action>
    </block>
</block>

<block type="page/html_under" name="underconstruction_message" as="underconstruction_message" template="page/html/under.phtml">
    <block type="cms/block" name="underconstruction" as="underconstruction">
        <action method="setBlockId">
            <block_id>underconstruction</block_id></action>
    </block>
</block>
```

Comment: <block type="page/html_prefooter" name="pre_footer" as="pre_footer" template="page/html/prefooter.phtml">    
    <block type="ibanners/view" name="ibanners.bottom_right" as="ibanners.bottom_right" after="-" template="ibanners/default.phtml">
     <action method="setGroupCode"><group_code>bottom_right</group_code></action>
    </block>
   </block>

Comment: <block type="page/html_nocart" name="no_cart_message" as="no_cart_message" template="page/html/nocart.phtml">
             <block type="cms/block" name="no_cart" as="no_cart">
     <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>no_cart</block_id></action>
    </block>
   </block>

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you haven't created the PHP class for `page/html_under` and `page/html_nocart`. You have to create those classes or refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6633307/understanding-magento-block-and-block-type)
to learn more about the `type` in the `block` layout.

Also, for your instance, you can get rid of that types and use `core/template` instead. See below:

```
<block type="core/template" name="no_cart_message" as="no_cart_message" template="page/html/nocart.phtml">
    <block type="cms/block" name="no_cart" as="no_cart">
        <action method="setBlockId">
            <block_id>no_cart</block_id>
        </action>
    </block>
</block>

<block type="core/template" name="underconstruction_message" as="underconstruction_message"
       template="page/html/under.phtml">
    <block type="cms/block" name="underconstruction" as="underconstruction">
        <action method="setBlockId">
            <block_id>underconstruction</block_id>
        </action>
    </block>
</block>
```